# How to clear Docker task history

Tags: linux, docker

When running docker in swarm mode, a history of past tasks accumulate as docker services are updated. Running `docker node ps` displays the log of tasks.

[image]

How do I clear this log without removing the service?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can adjust the history limit in swarm by running:

```
docker swarm update --task-history-limit=1
```

Which will only keep one previous task instead of the default 5. See the cli docs for more details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_update/

Comment: I was looking for something to clear it rather than limit it, but this will work. Cheers.

Comment: To remove individual tasks, you should be able to run `docker rm` on the container id. That's local per swarm host.

Comment: can I set the task history limit in daemon.json?

Comment: @tkyass not in daemon.json, but you can initialize it when creating the swarm: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_init/#options

Answer (score 4):

Instead this worked better to clear task history and show only the current running containers.

```
#docker swarm update --task-history-limit 0
```